# "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND SSH" in GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

On mysql workbench, I connected to a remote database with connection method, `Standard TCP/IP over SSH`. But I am having trouble to make the same connection in `node.js`.

The connection parameters I have used in MySQL workbench are:
`SSH Hostname`, `SSH Username`, `SSH Password`, `MySQL Hostname`, `MySQL Server Port`, `Username`. Other parameters including `Password` are left empty.

```
var mysql = require("mysql2");
var Client = require("ssh2").Client;
var ssh = new Client();

var db2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ssh
    .on("ready", function() {
      ssh.forwardOut(
        // source address, this can usually be any valid address
        "127.0.0.1",
        // source port, this can be any valid port number
        12345,
        // destination address (localhost here refers to the SSH server)
        "127.0.0.1",
        // destination port
        3306,
        function(err, stream) {
          console.log(stream);
          if (err) throw err; // SSH error: can also send error in promise ex. reject(err)
          // use `sql` connection as usual
          connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "MySQL Hostname",
            user: "username",
            password: "",
            database: "Default Schema",
            stream: stream
          });

          // send connection back in variable depending on success or not
          connnection.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              resolve(connection);
            } else {
              reject(err);
            }
          });
        }
      );
    })
    .connect({
      host: "SSH Hostname",
      port: 22,
      username: "SSH Username",
      password: "SSH Password"
    });
});


module.exports = db2;
```

The following is the error message:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND SSH Hostname SSH Hostname:22
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sihoon Kim\Desktop\development\inventory_management\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:306:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Rather than 'didn't work' what was the exact error and behaviour observed by you code?

Comment: added error code

Comment: Looks like` host: "SSH Hostname"`, or whatever the obfuscated hostname was, didn't have a DNS resolution.

Comment: *`SSH Hostname`* is not a legal DNS name. Fix the DNS name.

Comment: yea because its not the actual hostname..